# Match a pattern as long as it's not inside another set of alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple pattern:

```
LU ?[0-9]{2,10}{(?!\w)
```

Which should match

- `LU115087220`
- `LU 115087220`
- `:LU115087220.`
- etc.

Basically it should match as long as it's not inside another set of alphanumeric characters, e.g. `JOHNLU115087220`.

Note that this string is buried within a large multiline text, so I cannot use `^`.

I've tried with a non capturing group:

```
(?:\W|\s)LU ?[0-9]{2,10}(?!\w)
```

But running `regex.exec(str)` still captures the non alphanumeric char in the first group, e.g. `:LU115087220` -> `:LU115087220`(should have been `LU115087220`).

What am I missing here?

Comment: If this is reading a single line, use `^` at the start of your pattern to signify starting at the beginning of the line. If it's reading from a block of text, use `\b` at the start of your pattern to indicate beginning from a word break

Comment: Yeah I'm no regex guru and I don't fully understand your requirements, but you can try the following or similar: ^[^\w\d\s]*LU\s?[0-9]{2,10}[^\w\d\s+]*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `{` in your regex that makes every thing to fail. A negative lookahead containing `\w` almost means a word boundary `\b`. Enclose your pattern in it:

```
\bLU ?[0-9]{2,10}\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0bAJ6/1)

Comment: Haha, nice catch. I did not notice the extra `{`. I'm amazed it worked so far.